# Delete specific string in Subject

Tags: vba, outlook

Email Subject: [XX#123456] Banana ABC
Output: Banana ABC

My code is basically searching if the email subject contains "[XX#", if Yes, then it would then delete the rest of the string following after "[XX#123456]" and the Subject would now be Banana ABC.

However, using the code below, the output is:
Banana ABC123456] Banana ABC

```
For i = objItems.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set obj = objItems.item(i)
        If obj.Class = olMail And _
        (InStr(1, obj.ConversationTopic, "[XX#", vbTextCompare) > 0) Then
        Debug.Print "Found"
        Found = True
        obj.Subject = Replace(obj.Subject, "[XX#", (Mid(obj.Subject, InStr(obj.Subject, "[XX#") + 8)))

        obj.Save
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok got it. Just needed to remove "Replace" in my Code

```
obj.Subject = (Mid(obj.Subject, InStr(obj.Subject, "[XX#") + 8))
```